# [Javascript/HTML]: property causes TypeError: undefined, allthough property exists properly

Tags: javascript, html, properties, undefined, typeerror

My problem is as follows:

> - I intended to create a script that looks through **all** items on the page and making something with them
> - Then I intended to do that action with everything except a few objects that **contain** a specific class name
> - To do that, I created 3 divs - one with 1 dummy class and the skip-class, 1 with the skip-class only and one with the dummy class. Of course, I intended that all with the skip-class would be skipped and the others (1 div) would be  confronted with the action - but instead, I got a TypeError, with the comment, that `nodes[i].className` is undefined *(see below)*.
> - When i replace the condition with a other one, it works *(see below)*.
>     => What is wrong?

---

Here´s the code with TypeError:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="elm1 elm2"><p>This will not be shown</p></div>
        <div class="elm1"><p>This will be shown</p></div>
        <div class="elm2"><p>This will not be shown</p></div>
        <script>
            var nodes = document.body.childNodes;
            for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
                if (nodes[i].className.indexOf("elm2") > -1) {
                    nodes[i].style.display = "none";
                    nodes[i].className += "wasnotskipped";
                }
            }
        </script>
</html>
```

---

Here´s the code, changed and (somehow) does not output a TypeError:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="elm1 elm2"><p>This will not be shown</p></div>
        <div class="elm1"><p>This will be shown</p></div>
        <div class="elm2"><p>This will not be shown</p></div>
        <script>
            var nodes = document.body.childNodes;
            for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
                if (nodes[i].id == "skipme") {
                    nodes[i].style.display = "none";
                    nodes[i].className += " wasnotskipped";
                }
            }
        </script>
</html>
```

Comment: `childNodes` will give you text nodes, which have no class. You want `children`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to [torazaburo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/663031/torazaburo),
who explained to me the difference between `childNodes` (text nodes) and `children` (and solved the problem).
Just out of clarification reasons, i want to mention the correct code at this point:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="elm1 elm2"><p>This will not be shown</p></div>
        <div class="elm1"><p>This will be shown</p></div>
        <div class="elm2"><p>This will not be shown</p></div>
        <script>
            var childs = document.body.children;
            for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
                if (childs[i].className.indexOf("elm2") > -1) {
                    childs[i].style.display = "none";
                    childs[i].className += "wasnotskipped";
                }
            }
        </script>
</html>
```

I hope this answers the problem for all,
that in future will have the same as mine.
~ VicStudio